# Class change on hover: CSS vs jQuery (transition glich)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my site is build with multiple blocks, that contain of IMG, TITLE + TEXT, like this (they are in 3 columns):

```
<div class="element">
  <img class="responsive grey" src="img_src" />
  <article>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>text</p>
  </article>
</div>
```

The css for ".grey" (that I want with **transition**) is:

```
img.grey {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: gray;
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='0'><filter id='greyscale'><feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0' /></filter></svg>#greyscale");

  /* here should go transition */

}
```

Plus action on div:hover is:

```
.element:hover img.grey {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  filter: none;

  /* here should go transition */

}
```

As u can see, pointing mouse over whole DIV should trigger hover action for IMG only.

Problem is, that when I add transition to "img.grey" and ".element:hover img.grey", cause I want it to change smoothly, the effect becomes a bit glichy. I guess it's because "filter: none" along with "transition: transition_options;" are in colflict. Filter WITH no filter at the same time :) Sometimes it goes smooth, sometimes after hover I get white background, nvm. Many glitchy effects.

What I tried, was to delete ".element:hover img.grey {}" and simply add jQuery script that will toggle ".grey" class onmouseover / onmouseout (hover). I used standard "toggleClass()" inside of "$('element').hover()" function.

Also sth I found on css-tricks.com:

```
$('.element').hover(
       function(){ $("img").removeClass('grey') },
       function(){ $("img").addClass('grey') }
)
```

I thought that can help cause I am avoiding "filter: none VS transition" conflict. But both didn't work at all. Can anyone help me with it?

P.S. Didn't work means that there was no hover effect. After hover action images stayed in greyscale.

Comment: Did you get anything in the console? Can you make a jsfiddle or any sort of a live demo?

Comment: http://moje-miedzygorze.pl/index.php, here's what it is. Try to crazy-hover all elements on site and u should be able to see the glitch. Also, while scrolling down, menu getting glichty as u scroll mouse over divs (I guess).

Comment: It is the no-jQuery variant

Comment: Why do you have two transitions (one for `img.grey` and one for `.element:hover img.grey` )? Remove the hover one and see whether it changes anything?

Comment: Not sure if it'll help, but it might be some width/height issue, since the image (or the title) fit the container, during the transitions, the title seems to have a very slight shake, playing around with their dimensions for test like image width 96% instead of 100% ...

Comment: 96% didn't have any positive effect, it only added another glich :) True, double transition wasn't needed. For know I disabled all transition, except of  menu's. Not the best look I wanted, but still nice :) Ty for your time.

Comment: have you tried using `filter: grayscale(0);` in stead of `filter:none;` so there is some numeric value that can actually be transitioned. Seems to work fine in osx/chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/2gLdp60k/1/

Comment: Thx, it works. For now I disabled demo site, that I linked. Making some changes. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply want to have transition on image hover? Then you could try this — http://codepen.io/sergdenisov/pen/GJoyNz.

```
img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

img#lena-desaturate {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: gray;
    filter: url(#greyscale);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

    img#lena-desaturate:hover {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
        filter: none;
        filter: grayscale(0);
    }
```

Otherwise I don't understand your question.